# Не работает vue-router. Всегда открывается главная страница

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Есть проблема. Хочу использовать vue-router в своем пет-проекте, но он никак не хочет работать.
В чем смысл: создаю сам роутер, прописываю пути, но никого перехода не происходит, т.е. в строке браузера url меняется, но страница не меняется, остается мой main page.
На конкретном примере: открывается localhost -> на нем рендерится App.vue -> на этой странице есть router-link с прописанным to='/user' -> кликаю на эту ссылку -> в адресной строке url меняется, но никакого перехода не происходит, все так же остаюсь на App.vue.
Перелазил кучу тем, делаю так же, но не хочет работать и все тут. Горю на самом начале, буквально, и это печалит.
Подскажите мне, в чем косячу, никак не могу додуматься.
Vue-router устанавливал через npm
*npm install vue-router*

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>helper</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import router from "./route/router";

Vue.use(Vuetify)
export default new Vuetify({ })


new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

*router.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from "../App.vue";
import UsersList from "../components/UsersList.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {path: '/', component: App},
    {path: '/user', component: UsersList}
  ]
})
```

*UsersList.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    hello!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Hello"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      app
      clipped
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-view-dashboard</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <router-link to="/">Список</router-link>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
              <router-link to="/user">Наблюдаемые</router-link>
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: `{path: '/', component: App},` - неправильно. Нужно создать компонент-view для "главной страницы". `App` это корневой компонент, в его *template* должен быть `<router-view />`, куда и будут монтироваться компоненты-view указанные в конфигурации VueRouter'а. Почитай справку по vue-router, в общем :)

Comment: Еще, когда указываешь ссылку на "главную страницу" /, надо дописывать атрибут `exact` (то же самое касается и других путей, имеющих "дочерние" пути). Ну и по организации проекта: компонент-view "главной страницы" обычно называют Home, а все view держат в папке *src/views* (не в *src/components*, как обычные компоненты) - чтобы не путаться.

Comment: Спасибо, понял, как это работает теперь. Так же, спасибо, за советы по организации проекта!